# Let $(X,\|\ \cdot \|_X)$ be a normed space, take $f,g \in X^*$; $\ker(f)=\ker(g) \implies \exists\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$ s.t. $f=\alpha g$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $(X, \|\ \cdot \|_X)$ be a normed space and let $f,g \in X^*$, so $f,g : X \to \mathbb{F}$, where $X^*$ is the dual space of $X$. If $\ker(f)=\ker(g)$, then there exists a constant $\alpha$ such that $f=\alpha g$.

I have shown the result in the case where $X$ is finite dimension. However, I am having trouble with the infinte dimensional case. I'm thinking I will have to use the Hanh-Banach Theorem but am having trouble formulating my thoughts. Along the way (using Hanh-Banach) I've shown that if $X\neq\left\{ 0\right\}$ and $x\neq 0$ in $X$, there is a $f\in X^*$ with $\|\ f \|\ = 1$ and $f(x)=\|\ x \|\ $. Also that, given $x_1 \neq x_2$ there is a $f\in X^*$ with $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. I can provide proofs of both of these results if needed, they were just intermediate results that didn't quite end up getting me to my desired result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600816/linear-functionals-complex-vector-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to construct anything, as the two functionals are already given to you.

First, if $\ker f=X$, then $\ker g=X$ and $f=g=0$.

Now assume that $\ker f\subsetneq X$. Then there exists $y\in X$ such that $f(y)=1$. For any $x\in X$, $f(x-f(x)y)=0$, so $$x-f(x)y\in \ker f=\ker g.$$ Then $g(x-f(x)y)=0$, which we may write as $g(x)=g(y)\,f(x)$. So we may take $\alpha=g(y)$.

Comment: I was overthinking that a lot. Very clean and easy to follow, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)